# Using dynamic types with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What is the advantage of using dynamic type in the below code?

```
public static List<dynamic> GetEmployees()
{
    List<Employee> source = GenerateEmployeeCollection();
    var queryResult = from employee in source
                      where employee.Age > 20
                      select new { employee.FirstName, employee.Age };

    return queryResult.ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

And when would you go for returning a `List<dynamic>`.

Is to avoid creating types which would be used only very rarely?

Comment: My personal view here would be "don't do that". You're essentially taking all the nice type-safety that C# gives you and throwing it away because you don't want to add one more type to your system. There may be some circumstances in which you should do this, but I'm not seeing it here.

Comment: Speculative, but noting that anonymous types can't be referenced outside the scope of the method, possibly the original coder wasn't bothered with creating a definite type as you say (as well as spelling `query` incorrectly). The only possible benefit I can think of is there was some duck-typing commonality in the calling code with other methods returning types with `Age` and `FirstName` properties. Very dangerous stuff indeed.

Comment: Anonymous types can make working inside of a method/class a bit easier.  When you get to public boundaries on class methods that are meant to be called by external entities, favor types that make it clear what values they will return to forcing the caller to dive in to read the implementation to figure out what they'll be getting back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using anonymous types is great if you're making a query and only you are consuming the results in your method.

In this case, you're returning the data from your method. When returning data from a method, you want the consumer to know exactly what to expect (which they obviously don't with a dynamic type). Therefore, using a dynamic type is certainly not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

This clearly is a misuse of `dynamic` keyword - it should be used ONLY for object instances for which the type cannot be defined at the time of coding (which is e.g. the case when interacting with dynamic languages like Python). The author was just too lazy to define a type that he could return from the method.

Instead, the above code should be changed to this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Person(string firstName, int age)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        Age = age;
    }
}
...
public static List<Person> GetEmployees()
{
    List<Employee> source = GenerateEmployeeCollection();
    var queryResult = from employee in source
                      where employee.Age > 20
                      select new Person(employee.FirstName, employee.Age);

    return queryResult.ToList();
}
```

Regarding ToList(): The call to `ToList()` makes sense, since it 'materializes' the result of the previous LINQ query. Otherwise, the query would defer execution until actually iterated - and this is mostly not desirable in such scenarios as above (but note that you can drop the type argument here, it's inferred by the compiler anyway).

Answer (score 2):

A method cannot return an anonymous type (that's what you create with `new { employee.FirstName, employee.Age }`). Using `dynamic` bypasses this problem.

I wouldn't recommend using `dynamic` in this way: Either return `Employee`, or create another type with just those properties. The main reason is that `dynamic` doesn't explicitly tell those using `GetEmployees` what properties are available. It also has a minor runtime performance hit since it must resolve the property name at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If this method is not a part of the public API and is used only by you or your fellow developers, you can use the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for this.

```
public static List<Tuple<string, int>> GetEmployees()
{
    List<Employee> source = GenerateEmployeeCollection();
    var queryResult = from employee in source
                      where employee.Age > 20
                      select Tuple.Create(employee.FirstName, employee.Age);

    return queryResult.ToList();
}
```

Then access values as follows

```
var emps = GetEmployees();
var firstEmpName = emps[0].Item1; // FirstName
var firstEmpage = emps[0].Item2; // Age
```

I don't recommed to use it as a part of a public API since it's not clear which item contais what value. However, for the private usage sake, it's a nice way to get a temporary class for data.